# Assumptions behavior in Refine[Sin[n Pi/2]]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I don't understand why this first expression returns a correct result:

`In> Refine[Sin[n Pi/2], Element[n, Integers] && Mod[n, 2] == 1]`

`Out> I^(-1 + n)`

But this one returns a warning and an unexpected result:

`In> Refine[Sin[n Pi/2], Element[n, Integers] && EvenQ[n]]`

`Refine: Warning: one or more assumptions evaluated to False.`

`Out> Sin[(n \[Pi])/2]`

I don't understand the warning considering that `Mod[n,2]==1` and `OddQ[n]` return the same result for any Integer ....

Bonus question : how to force Mathematica to return `(-1)^n` instead of `I^(-1 + n)` ?

thanks :)

Comment: The message is correct. You are effectively evaluating `Refine[Sin[n Pi/2], Element[n, Integers] && False]`. Recall that `*Q[]` functions are designed to immediately return a Boolean value, so `EvenQ[n]` will immediately return `False` if `n` is symbolic. (This is a dupe, but I cannot find the original question about this right now.)

Comment: ahh ok just saw this in "possible issues" in the help for OddQ .... many thanks

Comment: To the "Bonus Question":  `(-1)^n `is not the same as `I^(-1+n) ` !  See `Table[{{n}, Sin[(n \[Pi])/2], I^(-1 + n), (-1)^n}, {n, -5, 5, 2}] ` .

Comment: yes @Artesit does thanks :)